# Obtener datos desde un formulario nieto al padre

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Trabajo en una aplicación Windows Forms, C#, IoC ninject. Como dice la pregunta obtener datos desde un formulario nieto al padre(del padre se llama a un formulario hijo y este llama a otro formulario) y desde este ultimo se toma los datos y se le pasa al padre.

Este es fácil de resolver utilizando variables globales, pero es una mala practica de programación.

Lo que pude hacer es implementar eventos bajo un patrón Singleton guiandome de este link [pasar datos entre formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2011/07/winforms-singleton-pasar-datos-entre.html)

Events

```
public static class CompleteEvent
{
    public delegate void CompleteHandler(CompleteEventArgs arg);
    public static event CompleteHandler Complete;
    public static event CompleteHandler PasarDosVariables;

    public static void RaiseEvent() { }
    public static void RaiseEvent(string strValor)
    {
        //if (Complete != null)
        //    Complete(new CompleteEventArgs());
        Complete?.Invoke(new CompleteEventArgs(strValor));
    }

    public static void RaiseEvent(int codigo, string valor)
    {
        PasarDosVariables?.Invoke(new CompleteEventArgs(codigo, valor));
    }
}

public class CompleteEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CompleteEventArgs() { }
    public CompleteEventArgs(string strValor)
    {
        StrValor = strValor;
    }

    public CompleteEventArgs(int codigo, string valor)
    {
        this.Codigo = codigo;
        this.StrValor = valor;
    }

    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string StrValor { get; set; }
}
```

RecolectarDatos

```
public class RecolectarDatos
{
    private static RecolectarDatos _datos;
    private RecolectarDatos()
    {

    }

    public static RecolectarDatos Instance()
    {
        //if (_controles == null)
        //    _controles = new ActivarControles();
        //return _controles;
        return _datos ?? (_datos = new RecolectarDatos());
    }

    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string StrValor { get; set; }
}
```

Mi código que me da problemas cuando uso el evento `CompleteEvent.PasarDosVariables` mas de una vez.

```
private void btnBuscarColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var argNombreEntidad = new ConstructorArgument("nombreEntidad", StrColour.NameEntity);
        var argT = new ConstructorArgument("t", EnumAsignacionTablas.Colour);
        var frm = CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmInputBox>(argNombreEntidad, argT);
        CompleteEvent.PasarDosVariables -= CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables;
        CompleteEvent.PasarDosVariables += CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables;    
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables(CompleteEventArgs arg)
    {
        try
        {
            if (vBool)
            {
                if (arg.Codigo != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.StrValor))
                {
                    if (DetalleItemColour.Count != 1)
                    {
                        var entity = new Colour()
                        {
                            ColourId = arg.Codigo,
                            Nombre = arg.StrValor
                        };
                        _detalleColour.Add(entity);
                        dgvColor.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                        dgvColor.DataSource = DetalleItemColour;
                        CompleteEvent.RaiseEvent();
                        arg.Codigo = 0;
                        arg.StrValor = String.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBoxEx.EnableGlass = false;
                        MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Solo se permite un solo Color", StrColour.NameEntity,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        vBool = false;
                        arg.Codigo = 0;
                        arg.StrValor = String.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBoxEx.Show(this, $"Error:{e.Message}", "Error Inesperado", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void txtMarca_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
        {
            var argNombreEntidad = new ConstructorArgument("nombreEntidad", StrMarca.NameEntity);
            var argT = new ConstructorArgument("t", EnumAsignacionTablas.Marca);
            var frm = CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmInputBox>(argNombreEntidad, argT);
            CompleteEvent.PasarDosVariables -= CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables1;
            CompleteEvent.PasarDosVariables += CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables1;
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void CompleteEvent_PasarDosVariables1(CompleteEventArgs arg)
    {
        if (arg.Codigo != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg.StrValor))
        {
            txtMarcaId.Text = Convert.ToString(arg.Codigo);
            txtMarca.Text = arg.StrValor;
            CompleteEvent.RaiseEvent();
            arg.Codigo = 0;
            arg.StrValor = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

El problema es que cuando utilizo un evento se activa el otro evento y me chanca los datos.

[image: duplicado de datos]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He logrado implementar lo que me recomendó @Jesus Angulo me ha funcionado y lo pongo como respuesta espero este bien el uso ya que me dio pocos argumentos. Voy a pasar información desde un formulario hijo al padre.

Formulario hijo(frmBusqueda)

```
public FrmBusqueda(string title, EnumAsignacionTablas t)
        {
            _titulo = title;
            _table = t;
            CompleteEvent.Complete += CompleteEvent_Complete;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    public FrmBusqueda(string title, EnumAsignacionTablas t, IMessageHub evenHub) : this(title, t)
    {
        _eventHub = evenHub;
    }

private void ObtenerId()
        {
            if (dgvBusqueda.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    _idRow = Convert.ToInt32(dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    _desRow = Convert.ToString(dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                }
                _eventHub.Publish(new ColorSelected {Codigo = _idRow, StrValor = _desRow});
            }
        }
```

Formulario padre(frmArticulo)

```
private void btnBuscarColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var argNombreEntidad = new ConstructorArgument("title", StrColour.NameEntity);
            var argT = new ConstructorArgument("t", EnumAsignacionTablas.Colour);
            var frm = CompositionRoot.Resolve<FrmBusqueda>(argNombreEntidad, argT);  
        _eventHub.Subscribe<ColorSelected>(OnColorSelected); 
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void OnColorSelected(ColorSelected colorEvent)
    {
        if (colorEvent.Codigo != 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(colorEvent.StrValor))
        {
            if (DetalleItemColour.Count != 1)
            {
                var entity = new Colour()
                {
                    ColourId = colorEvent.Codigo,
                    Nombre = colorEvent.StrValor
                };
                _detalleColour.Add(entity);
                dgvColor.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dgvColor.DataSource = DetalleItemColour;

                //De suscribir
                _eventHub.ClearSubscriptions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBoxEx.EnableGlass = false;
                MessageBoxEx.Show(this, "Solo se permite un solo Color", StrColour.NameEntity,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                vBool = false;
                colorEvent.Codigo = 0;
                colorEvent.StrValor = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }`
```

Clase ColorSelected

```
public class ColorSelected
    {
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string StrValor { get; set; }
    }
```

Me esta funcionado si hay algún comentario o corrección bienvenidos sean.

Answer (score 5):

Probablemente lo que pueda ayudarte es una mejor implementacion del patron Pub/Sub, que justamente, basandose en eventos permite una comunicacion desacoplada entre componentes sin relacion directa en nuestra aplicacion.

## Implementar el patron EventAggregator

Usando [Easy.MessageHub](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.MessageHub) podemos crear subscripciones a eventos dentro de nuestra aplicacion.

En el constructor de nuestro formulario nos subscribimos a los eventos que necesitamos:

```
     public FrmMain(IMessageHub eventHub)
     {
        _eventHub = eventHub;
        //_eventHub.Subscribe<ColorSelected>(p => Console.WriteLine($"Id is: {p.Color}"));
        _eventHub.Subscribe<ColorSelected>(OnColorSelected);
     }

     private void OnColorSelected(ColorSelected colorEvent)
     {
         ...
         var entity = new Colour()
         {
             ColourId = colorEvent.Codigo,
             Nombre = colorEvent.StrValor
         };
         _detalleColour.Add(entity);
         dgvColor.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
         dgvColor.DataSource = DetalleItemColour;
   
        ...
        //algun evento para que el padre se entere
        _eventHub.Publish(new CompletedEvent());
     }
```

**Como puedes ver tenemos la posiblidad de lanzar una infinidad diferente de eventos sin tener que definirlos, solo empleamos una clase como contrato para dicho evento y podemos subscribirnos y de-subscribirnos de ellos para comunicar de manera desacoplada nuestra aplicacion.**

> El nieto lanza una clase de evento que el hijo escucha y el hijo lanza un evento que el padre finalmente procesa.

[image: Pub/Sub events]

> Finalmente, para usar IMessageHub, registramos la implementacion en nuestro contenedor IoC (porque usar clases estaticas, aunque mas faciles, son consideradas una mala practica tambien).

```
kernel.Bind<IMessageHub>().ToConstant(MessageHub.Instance);
```

Comment: tengo que instalar Install-Package Easy.MessageHub?

Comment: Como le envio lo que tomo en el nieto al padre por ejemplo

Comment: `private void ObtenerId()
        {
            if (dgvBusqueda.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    _idRow = Convert.ToInt32(dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
                    _desRow = Convert.ToString(dgvBusqueda.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
                }
                CompleteEvent.RaiseEvent(_idRow, _desRow);
            }
        }`

Comment: Estas usando los eventos que ya tengo creados como PasarDosVariables o estas desechando lo que ya había creado, esa parte no entiendo? con tu técnica puedes crear eventos?

Comment: Si @pedro-avila, con Easy.MessageHub puedes enviar eventos, basta con usar clases diferentes para diferentes mensajes. Y no estoy usando tus eventos porque no son muy claros, algo como ColorSelected , etc podria ser mas apropiado. Saludos

Comment: Tendrás un ejemplo mas concreto o un link donde lo pueda estudiar más a fondo o donde se implemente un caso o la manera de como implementarlo, en el ejemplo que pones ColorSelected veo que es una clase verdad.

Comment: Hola @jesus-angulo no es muy claro el ejemplo que pones en tu respuesta tienes algun link que muestre un ejemplo mas claro de la implementación que me recomiendas

Comment: Estas seguro que en ninject se define singleton usando ToConstant() ? me suena raro